# angular select directive and having the selected option populate a view

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm pretty new to angular, but am having trouble using the select directive

Here is my html

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyTestCtrl">
        <button ng-click="loadData()">LOAD ME</button>
        <button ng-click="sendData()">SEND ME</button>
        <div>
            <div>{{formObject}}</div>
            <div>My name is {{_userView.name}}</div>
            <div>I like to go {{formObject.activity_id.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <div>

        <!--For solution 1 -->
        <select ng-model="formObject.user_id"                  
                ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in userStore">                        
        </select>

        <!--For solution 2 -->
        <select ng-model="formObject.activity_id"                
                ng-options="o.name for o in activityStore track by o.id">                        
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller I have a bunch of data stores that are used to populate the options of a select directive. Along with the id and name, they have other meta data will be used for display purposes

Also in the controller there is a form object that holds the ids that will be pass back and forth to the server. The server will also response with an object with ids

```
function MyTestCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.formObject = {
        user_id: null,
        activity_id: null
    };

    $scope.userStore = [
        {id:50, name: 'Chris R.', address:'456 Far Away'},
        {id:65, name: 'Ryan S.',  address:'029 Somewhat Near'},
        {id:70, name: 'Tommy K.', address:'856 Underground'}
    ];

    $scope.activityStore = [
        {id:10, name: 'Running'},
        {id:13, name: 'Swimming'},
        {id:16, name: 'Biking'}
    ];
    ...
}
```

When a selection is made from a dropdown, the display should update itself accordingly with the appropriate data
When data is loaded from the server, the display should update itself accordingly with the appropriate data
When data is sent to the server, it needs to be in the correct format (ids only, no extra data)

I have some solutions in mind, but am hoping to find a more "angular" approach. Perhaps something I've missing from ng-options. It is almost like I want the ids in the form object to act as foreign keys to the data in the data stores

**Solution 1:**
Set up $scope.$watch() on the ids in the form object and have it search the data stores when there is a change. Store the founded object from the data store into a private model and use that private model in the view for display

**Solution 2:**
Bind the object to the form object and use the form object directly for display. When data is loaded, search the data stores for the object and override the form id with the object. When data is sent, pluck the id from the object and assign it to the form id. Unfortunately this method has a side effect of blanking out the dropdown after the plucking step

Here is the a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D95c3/

Is there a better, more angular way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `ng-change` to call a function on select change?

```
<select ng-model="formObject.user_id" ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in userStore" ng-change="changeUser()"></select>
```

In the `changeUser` function can then just reference the `formObject.user_id` field which will be populated by the `ng-model`

Comment: Would changeUser() do the same thing as the $scope.$watch() like

    `$scope.changeUser = function() {
        var found = $filter('filter')($scope.userStore, {id: $scope.formObject.user_id}, true);        
        if (found.length) {
           $scope._userView = found[0];
        }
    }`

and I would still use `<div>My name is {{_userView.name}}</div>` to display the data?

Comment: Yes, you will have full access to `$scope.formObject` in the `changeUser` function as AngularJS is binding to that via `ng-model`.